# Serilog in .NET MAUI 7

Tags: .net, maui

When I try to use *Serilog* with.NET MAUI, a following error is retrieved:

*Unable to resolve service for type *Serilog.ILogger* while attempting to activate ConfiguradorMS.ViewModel.HomeViewModel.*

Here goes my config on MauiProgram.cs file:

var flushInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
var file = Path.Combine("logClient-.log");

```
using Serilog;

 var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
     .MinimumLevel.Debug()
     .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Warning)
     .Enrich.FromLogContext()
     .WriteTo.File(file, flushToDiskInterval: flushInterval, encoding: System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, retainedFileCountLimit: 22)
     .CreateLogger();


builder.Services.AddLogging(lg => lg.AddSerilog(logger));
```

I`ve tried many another types of config, like *builder.Logging.AddSerilog(logger)* etc. Nothing works

Comment: You can [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/). This may help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I`ve resolved adding manually the ILogger on Singleton Service Pipeline:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILogger>(logger);
```